# I need to check is there any duplicate array exist or not

Tags: javascript, jquery

var myarray = [
{
"msf": "3.98",
"ptc": "5.00"
},
{
"msf": "3.98",
"ptc": "1.00"
},
{
"msf": "3.98",
"ptc": "1.00"
}
]

Expect answer is : true

Comment: what have you tried so far? Where is your attempt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to know *if* there are duplicates, not caring which they are, you can use a 'Set' to see if the number of unique elements is less than the original array:

```
const hasduplicates = new Set(myarray.map(JSON.stringify)).size < myarray.length;
```

POC to play around with:

```js
const myarray = [ { "msf": "3.98", "ptc": "5.00" }, { "msf": "3.98", "ptc": "1.00" }, { "msf": "3.98", "ptc": "1.00" } ];

let set=  new Set(myarray.map(JSON.stringify));
console.log(...set); //just for proof of concept

const hasduplicates = set.size < myarray.length;
console.log('Has duplicates: ', hasduplicates);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a hacky way.
But I can sure there's a better way.

```js
var myarray = [ { "msf": "3.98", "ptc": "5.00" }, { "msf": "3.98", "ptc": "1.00" }, { "msf": "3.98", "ptc": "1.00" } ]
const seen=[];
const dupe=[];
myarray.forEach(e=>(seen.includes(JSON.stringify(e))?dupe:seen).push(seen.includes(JSON.stringify(e))?e:JSON.stringify(e)))
console.log(dupe);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Sets:

```
// combine the properties so Set can be used
let uniqueArrayString = [
    ...new Set(myArray.map((item) => item.msf + '-' + item.ptc)),
];
// separate the msf and ptc
let uniqueArrayObject = uniqueArrayString.map((item) => {
    return {
        msf: item.split('-')[0],
        ptc: item.split('-')[1],
    };
});
```